# Tracing how my path is being set

Tags: unix, path, csh

Is there a way (in UNIX) to trace how my `$PATH` is set?

I have an entry in my path that I don't want, but I just can't find the source to remove it for good. I am running Solaris 10 and CSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is set in `/home/<your_user>/.profile` or `/home/<your_user>/.bash_profile`.

Check it doing

```
grep -l PATH /home/<your_user>/.* 2>/dev/null
```

that will point the .files that are defining this variable.